# IOS insert layout programmatically

Tags: ios, storyboard

In android we can create a separate xml layout and can include it in another layout. I want to achieve same in IOS. I want to create a custom layout and want to include it programmatically to another layout.

How to do it with IOS?

I am using Xcode with swift 2.3.

Comment: you want to add one view to another?

Comment: are you asking if you want to create a view and then add that view in another view? If yes the answer is to use the method - view.addSubview

Comment: You may also be looking for a container view controller. This lets you embed another view controller in a control.

Comment: If what you want is to define properties that will create a layout in a specific way and use it through out various screens, you might want to have a look at subclassing views. Or using xib (this approach is outdated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it.
First of all you have to create simple fileName.swift file

[image: create File]

select this one.

[image: swiftFile]

Give class Name as your file name (Here i gave sample) and choose UIView (Because we are creating a simple View.)
[image: class Name]

Now again Create View (it will create a .xib file where you can design your layout)

[image: View Image]

Now you select View and create your UI like this.

[image: createView]

now open sample.swift (Here) and write simple code.

[image: code file]

now you can use this view to add any where in your project.
To add this add simple View in any StoryBoard ViewController (Drag and Drop)

[image: storyView]

Now Main Step to add your Custom View in your View
Select your View from ViewController (where you want to add this)
and simple Write class name in identity Inspector.

[image: class Name]

Now Simple Run the project and Bingo..

[image: Output]

Comment: and how can i reference labels and buttons of my custom ui

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build view programmatically you might want to user

https://github.com/SnapKit for swift.

https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry for objc.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS we called them views.

You can use `addSubView` to add another view inside a view.

Example:

```
[self.view addSubView: yourcustomView]; //Where self.view is the parent view.
```